# Running ruby script through php as www-data

Tags: linux, php, ruby

I am running a php application on an apache server. From the php application I need to run a ruby script on the command line. I have verified that running the script directly from a terminal as `user`, works properly. The local ruby environment for `user` is setup by setting a path variable and sourcing `/home/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm` which allows the script to load the requirements with `require` statements.

Now through the php application the script fails at these require statements and I assume this is because there is no ruby environment setup for the `www-data` user. I have never used ruby before and I am not sure what the correct way would be of setting that environment

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. I posted the answer to my question on SO. Hope it helps!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40224414/1672458

> I was able to figure this out. First, I [installed
>   rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#installation) as a multi-user
>   installation to ensure the `www-data` account can access it.
>
> ```
> $ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
> ```
>
> Install the desired ruby version, in my case 2.3.1, then set rvm to
>   use it:
>
> ```
> $ rvm install 2.3.1
> $ rvm use 2.3.1
> ```
>
> Run `gem` to install any gems that are needed. Because rvm is a
>   multi-user installation, these gems are stored to the system and not
>   your specific user.
>
> ```
> $ gem install packagename
> ```
>
> I don't know if this is necessary, but I would close the SSH session
>   and reopen it. rvm messes with environment variables, so better safe
>   than sorry.
>
> Run `env` to print all environment variables. `printenv` also works if
>   `env` doesn't for some reason. You'll get a big list of everything
>   set, you only need the ruby-related ones. **Do not copy/paste these
>   values, they are examples I pulled from my system. Yours will be
>   different!**
>
> ```
> PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/steven/bin:/home/steven/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
> rvm_bin_path=/usr/local/rvm/bin
> GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
> IRBRC=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/.irbrc
> MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1
> rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm
> rvm_prefix=/usr/local
> rvm_ruby_string=ruby-2.3.1
> GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global
> RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.3.1
> ```
>
> Now we need PHP to recognize these variables. You'll need to find the
>   right file on your system, which can be tricky. I don't have a way of
>   knowing which one is correct, I used trial and error.
>
> The file on my system is `/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. Add
>   **all** of the environment variables you previously grabbed into this file with the below format. Note that you DO need `PATH` in here as
>   well!
>
> ```
> env[rvm_path] = /usr/local/rvm
> env[rvm_prefix] = /usr/local
> ```
>
> Now restart `php-fpm`. Your service name may be different from mine;
>   I'm using the 5.6 build from
>   [ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php).
>
> Ubuntu 15.04 and newer (systemd):
>
> ```
> $ sudo systemctl restart php5.6-fpm
> ```
>
> Ubuntu 14.10 and newer:
>
> ```
> $ sudo service php5.6-fpm restart
> ```
>
> Finally, in the script itself you'll need to `cd` to the directory
>   you're running the `bundle` command from. My short script is this:
>
> ```bash
> cd /opt/slate
> /usr/bin/git reset --hard
> /usr/bin/git pull
> bundle exec middleman build --clean
> cp -R /opt/slate/build/* /var/www/docs
> ```
>
> Works for me!